# Proper way to get dimensions of a nested iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a javascript in the head tag of a domain that is not mine that is looking for DIVs on the page to measure the height and width. The names of the DIVs are in an array. Each div has an undefined size. The size of the div will grow based on an iframe that loads from a different domain. The div may not always be the same size as the iframe so the div is not a reliable element to pull the size of. Therefore, I must measure the iframe. However, my problem is that my code loads in the head and sometimes loads before the div's size is defined which means the iframe isn't ready yet. I then do a setTimeout to check if the div's height and width is greater than 1. However, I notice that after the div and iframe content visually appears on the screen, there is a delay of a few seconds before the console logs the size of the iframe. I need the dimensions as soon as the iframe content loads. How can I make this code more efficient?

**Head Tag of Page**

```
var oDv = ["div-0", "div-1", "div-2"];
<script src="mydomain.js"></script>
```

**Body of Page**

```
<div id="div-0">
<script src="gets-an-iframe-from-some-other-domain.js"></script>
```

**mydomain.js (aka my script)**

```
window.addEventListener('load', pageFullyLoaded, false);
function pageFullyLoaded(e) {
    var index;
    for (index = 0; index < oDv.length; index++){
        measure(oDv[index]);
    }
}
function measure(div){  
    var divElement = document.getElementById(div);
    if(divElement === null){
        return;
    }
    var iframeElement = document.getElementById(div).getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
    var iframeDimensions = window.getComputedStyle(iframeElement, null);
    var iframeHeight = parseInt(iframeDimensions.getPropertyValue("height"));
    var iframeWidth = parseInt(iframeDimensions.getPropertyValue("width"));
    if((iframeHeight || iframeWidth) == 1){
        timer();
    }
    else{
        console.log(iframeHeight+" "+iframeWidth);
    }
}
function timer(){
    var T = setInterval(function(){
            if((iframeHeight || iframeWidth) == 1){
                iframeHeight = parseInt(iframeDimensions.getPropertyValue("height"));
                iframeWidth = parseInt(iframeDimensions.getPropertyValue("width"));                 
            }
            else{
                clearInterval(T);
            }
}, 100);
```

**UPDATE 1**
I think I need to work around the window.addEventListener('load', pageFullyLoaded, false); because sometimes the first DIV loads while the rest of the page content is still loading. And sometimes the iframe loads before the page content is done. Therefore the top DIV/iframe are ready to be measured but my code hasn't started because it is still waiting for the the entire page to load. Also, I'd like to get away from using the setTimeout if possible.

**UPDATE 2**
I tried the following code but I get the following error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null". I believe this is because when I check for this the DIV exists but the iFrame does not yet. I don't want to try adding an event listener to the window for the page to have loaded because I need the size as soon as possible.

```
    function iframeReady(div){
    console.log(div+' Start Function');
    var iframe = document.getElementById(div).getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
    iframe.onload = function() {
        console.log('iFrame loaded');
        var iframeDimensions = window.getComputedStyle(iframe, null);
        var iframeHeight = parseInt(iframeDimensions.getPropertyValue("height"));
        var iframeWidth = parseInt(iframeDimensions.getPropertyValue("width"));
        console.log('iframeLoaded '+div+' iframe dimensions: '+iframeWidth+'x'+iframeHeight);
    }
}
iframeReady('a-div-id');
```

In the above I see the following in the console:

- a-div-id Start Function
- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null

I guess I'll just need to put the above into a settimeout loop to keep checking for the existence of the iframe first?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the `iframe.onload` event

```
var iframe = document.getElementByTagName("iframe")[0];
iframe.onload = function() {
    console.log(iframe.getBoundingClientRect());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was a good idea but I don't think it is going to work. On a test page I tried this and everything is great. However, when I flip it on to the client's page their iframes never stop loading. There might be some type of a timing even or something running that's keeping it from reporting back fully loaded?

Comment: Hard to tell... If you can share the script you are loading from the client page, I can take a look.